# Changes to Touch ID warning after restarting iPhone due to unresponsive app

Tags: iphone, touch-id

This morning I restarted my iPhone 7 due to an unresponsive app - Facebook, which does not use Touch ID. On restart I had to enter my passcode, which was to be expected after a reboot.

I then tried to view some banking apps, which require Touch ID, the first required my passcode, rather than Touch ID, I thought this was strange, but carried on. The second banking app showed a Touch ID error. Going back to the first app showed the error below.

I have not made any changes to Touch ID since setting up the phone months ago (at which point I filled all 5 slots for fingerprints), so am slightly concerned about this warning.

What could have caused this message? And what is the safest course of action?

[image]

Comment: As far as I could tell, none of my fingerprints had been changed, all 5 still unlocked the iPhone, but I deleted them and changed them anyway. I got the same warning message, but expected it, as I had changed the fingerprints.

Comment: Can you please update the question with your current iOS version, iOS version when you asked the question, and if the problem is still occuring?

Comment: This only happened once.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be an issue with your bank's app. If I remember correctly, apps *are* notified anytime a touchID change is made, so things like 1Password will request your Master Password to sign in. This popup seems to be of your bank's design, and a software glitch made your phone think there was a change in TouchID.

For future reference, you can confirm that all fingers enrolled in touchID are yours by going to **Settings > Touch ID & Passcode.** Then scroll to the part of the pane where it shows your touchID fingerprints:

[image]

Now, put each registered finger on the sensor and wait until the fingerprint is highlighted, like so:

[image]

Ensure that each fingerprint is yours by making sure that your fingers highlight **all** of the fingerprint options.

Or, you could just set touchID up again for all your fingers.